# Add-in Store and Installed Add-ins no longer appearing

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app, outlook-2016

My team works on an add-in for Microsoft Outlook, and recently we’ve been receiving reports from certain users that our add-in has disappeared from their message surface and from the “...” menu (More actions) on the message surface.  In addition, any other add-ins they’d installed and the add-in store itself are gone.  The add-ins and add-in store have also disappeared from the compose view’s toolbar.  It does not look like these users did anything to cause this.

We’ve gotten reports of this issue both from Outlook Web App users and Outlook 2016 users, but no one on my team has been able to reproduce the issue on one of our own accounts.  So far, we’ve only seen this issue happen with outlook.com and hotmail.com users.

Do you know what could be responsible for this behavior?  If so, do you know if there is any way we or our users could prevent this from happening?

Comment: Check if you can find the add-ins recently installed there, if yes, turn off/uninstall it temporarily and see if there is any improvement.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Can you clarify where to find the add-ins? Unfortunately they seem to not be found anywhere.

Comment: You can log in on the web and observe your list of add-ins.

Comment: Are there any old COM add-ins, and can you temporarily disable/remove?  Are you putting a proxy in-between and the client is no longer seeing a good certificate? (Outlook add-ins seem to be very sensitive around the certificate).  I presume the mail accounts have not been reconfigured to be POP3/IMAP which also don't support mail add-ins, or they have configured more than one mail account, and are sitting in a default account which is POP3/IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Steve for asking this question. Can you please check if you can find add-ins in the overflow flow as in following screenshot?

[image]