# The OWA Add-Ins Ribbon is missing for some users

Tags: office365, add-in, office365-apps, outlook-web-app

We are having an issue where a subset of users cannot see the Add-Ins ribbon when using outlook.office.com . Most users can see the ribbon. They have the add-ins group on the message surface but it does not show on the popdown window using the ... . This is all add-ins, webex, polls, and admin managed. The issue persists across browsers, but if a user who does see the add-ins opens a users mailbox who doesn't they are there. Support is not helpful as of yet. Any ideas?

Tried redeploying some apps, resetting users layouts, clearing cache

[Users with add-ins ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhSw6.png)
[User with no add-in ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rML6A.png)

Comment: Got any error logs?  Got some code or settings so someone can even start trying to figure out how this generalized problem exists?

Comment: Added in screen shots for connect, no error logs, this is not related to custom code

Comment: Normally StackOverflow discourages images but they do show the issue in question.  Have you looked at this post to see if anything there helps? -->
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347106/add-in-store-and-installed-add-ins-no-longer-appearing?rq=2

Comment: That post essentially is the same issue, some users have it in the overflow, others do not.

Comment: The picture comment is mainly because we can't fix code we can't copy and paste.  But in that post that i suggested, did that post help you resolve your issue?

Comment: @easleyfixed no that post did not resolve the issue

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Alas personally this isn't my specialty as I build my own things, but wanted to offer these guidances to help encourage the diehards in this subject to pinpoint a solution for you.